# Bought a phone from asia

Tags: data-connection

I live in the UK I bought the new htc one m9+ from asia andy data doesnt work it says service is unavailable please if anyone has any ideas

Answer (score 0):

You can check the phone specifications and accordingly contact your service provider. Phones are manufactured keeping in mind the cellular network operating specifications of a particular country/region. Probably the following link might help you understand about the cellular network operating frequencies: [Wiki - Cellular frequencies](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Cellular_frequencies)